# Getting an Pig error:Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_LONG 2 time(s)

Tags: apache-pig

> [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_LONG 2 time(s).

```
avg_qtime1 = FOREACH avg_qtime GENERATE
                     qid,
                     ToDate((long)avg*1000) as avg_ans_time;
```

Comment: Its not an error, its a warn !

Comment: Ignore it, not an error. warning msg..

Comment: I have corrected some of the formatting in your question; however, it is still in need of improvement. Can you describe what you were trying to do, how you were trying to do it, what the problem was you encountered, and how you have tried to fix it so far before asking for help?

Comment: it is not the culprit, just a warning. Please provide complete log or at least exception.

Comment: your avg field seems to be chararray and it cannot be casted in a way you did. If you are loading this data from text file load avg field as long instead of chararray

Answer (score 0):

```
(long)avg*1000
```

At least here, you multiply long with int. It should be

```
(long)avg*1000L
```

Answer (score 0):

Never ignore these warnings, make sure there is no impact. the error message can derail you to some where but this is the culprit. Pig doesn't do good job in implicit conversion, even with int to long. See the following ticket - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-5330 
If the above warning is from a column you use for JOINs, COUNTs, ORDER BYs it will fail.